# Finding matched pairs in two character strings

Tags: r, stringr

I have a dataset that looks like the example I've created below

```
ex_data <- data.frame(
  House = c("House 1", "House 2", "House 3"),
  features = c("Roof, Walls, Windows, Oven", "Oven, Roof, Walls, TV", "Size, Oven, Bedrooms"),
  attributes = c("Large, White, 5, Whirlpool", "Samsung, Large, White, Sony", "4000 sq ft, KitchenAid, 5")
)
```

Essentially my dataset has the main grouper (`House`) and has characteristics about that House. The characteristics are comma-separated values.

I am trying to figure out how to find the Oven and the brand that is attributed to the Oven in each house. I know that each house has an oven in the `features` string but I don't know how to find the corresponding brand.

My thinking is that I would use the function `separate` to create a new column for each feature and attribute however my real dataset has up to 100 comma-separated `features/attributes`.

I would like the end result to look like this

```
ex_data_result <- data.frame(
  House = c("House 1", "House 2", "House 3"),
  features = c("Oven", "Oven", "Oven"),
  attributes = c("Whirlpool", "Samsung", "KitchenAid")
)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Some elements are 'Oven Large', are you matching substring

Comment: @akrun The strings are matched. For example, in `House 1` the pairs would be `(Roof, Large)`, `(Walls, White)`, `(Windows, 5)`, and `(Oven, Whirlpool)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `separate_rows` from `tidyr` to split the columns 'features', 'attributes' to long format by specifying the `sep` as `,` followed by zero or more digits, then `filter` the rows where 'features' is 'Oven'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
 ex_data %>% 
  separate_rows(features, attributes, sep=",\\s*") %>%
  filter(features == 'Oven')
```

Comment: Ah thank you @akrun. I figured `separate` was the way to go but didn't know about `separate_rows`. I'm not super familiar with regex. Could you explain what `\\s*` is doing?

Comment: @jackbio thanks.  Here, the `\\s` implies space in regex and `*` is zero or more.  So, we are basically spliting at `,` followed by any spaces afterwards

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string on `","` for `features` and `attributes` and select the corresponding `attributes` where `features = "Oven"`.

In base R, you can do this with `strsplit` and `mapply` :

```
ex_data$Brand <- mapply(function(x, y) y[x == 'Oven'], 
             strsplit(ex_data$features,", "), strsplit(ex_data$attributes,", "))

ex_data
#    House                   features                  attributes      Brand
#1 House 1 Roof, Walls, Windows, Oven  Large, White, 5, Whirlpool  Whirlpool
#2 House 2      Oven, Roof, Walls, TV Samsung, Large, White, Sony    Samsung
#3 House 3       Size, Oven, Bedrooms   4000 sq ft, KitchenAid, 5 KitchenAid
```